# How do I load an image from parse in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I was wondering if anyone can help me, I'm new to app developing 
I am uploading images from my app to parse with no problem with help from parse documentation.

```
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(scaledImage)
    let imageFile: PFFile = PFFile(data: imageData)

    var userPhoto = PFObject(className: "postString")
    userPhoto["imageFile"] = imageFile
    userPhoto.saveInBackground()
```

but when i add the code to retrieve the image back, I'm a bit lost :/

```
let userImageFile = anotherPhoto["imageFile"] as PFFile
userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
(imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  if !error {
     let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
   }
}
```

where is the "anotherPhoto" coming from ? Parse did say "Here we retrieve the image file off another UserPhoto named anotherPhoto:"

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. This looks like a question about the Parse API rather than about Swift in particular.

Answer (score 5):

`anotherPhoto` would be an instance of your `postString` (`userPhoto` in your upload example). The file downloading example that would work for you is like this:

```
let userImageFile = userPhoto["imageFile"] as PFFile
userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if !error {
        let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
    }
}
```

Any PFFile must be referenced from a normal PFObject or it cannot be retrieved. PFFile objects themselves will not show up in the data browser.

Comment: what if i want to retrieve the image within another function, do i need to declare userPhoto globally ?

Comment: Globals are probably not the answer, but yes, you need to have a reference to that object. If you are working with the current logged-in user, there'a a global PFUser.currentUser() already, otherwise you may have a user object as the result of a query.

Comment: thank you, i got it to work, i have another question if you don't mind, how do i check to see if a key holds any data, for example, on parse, i have a key called imageFile, how do i check if its empty or not before i load in into a variable ? :/