# Async With Parse

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, parse-platform

I'm building an app based around pictures. So it's very important for me to retrieve all images asyncronously like Instagram does. I understand that this function...

```
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects as! [PFObjects] {
            for object in objects {
                objectsArray.append(object)
            }
        }
    }
```

...is asynchronous. But I want a way to load images from Parse into a table asynchronously so it loads images while scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at PFImageView's function `loadInBackground()`.

For example, if you are using a PFTableViewController with a PFTableViewCell, you can do the following

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as! CustomTableViewCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = CustomTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
    }

    if let name = object?["name"] as? String {
        cell.nameLbl.text = name
    }

    var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
    cell.imgView.image = initialThumbnail
    if let thumbnail = object?["photo"] as? PFFile {
        cell.imgView.file = thumbnail
        cell.imgView.loadInBackground()
    }

    return cell
}
```

with PFTableViewCell having

```
class CustomCell: PFTableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: PFImageView!
}
```

Also from another SO [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717302/how-do-i-load-an-image-from-parse-in-swift), you can try this:

```
let userImageFile = userPhoto["imageFile"] as PFFile
userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if !error {
        let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot!